# check if all asynchronous http requests are done

Tags: javascript, dojo

So I have multiple asynchronous HTTP requests in my pure JS app, but while they load they block the  effective work with the app. I want to show a loading indicator for that, I have no idea how I can do it with asynchronous requests.

What I tried.
I checked how many requests I fired in an array while these are not done I showed a loading indicator, but because these are asynchronous after the first set was done there came in another set, because of dependencies to each other.

Is there something to solve this problem?

Comment: Generally speaking, you can use [`Promise.all(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), but we can't really help you further without any code.

Comment: I tied that. but it's also would involve changing the code too much. I just need a general answer, I would do the code myself.  thanks

Comment: This is a general answer. I have written you a little example - your code should be able to be rewritten in the same way. If not, I suspect some needed refactoring. If I am wrong, we need your code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have code like so:

```
function doAjax(params, callback) {
   // ...
   callback(ajaxResponse, error);
}

function doRequests() {
   doAjax(params, (success, error) => {
       if(error) console.error(error);
       console.log(success);
   });

   doAjax(params2, (success, error) => /* ... */);

   // ...
}
```

You can easily rewrite that into Promises:

```
function doAjax(params) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // ...

       if(error) reject(error);
       else resolve(ajaxResponse;
   });
}

function doRequests() {
   showLoader();

   Promise.all(doAjax(params), doAjax(params2), /* ... */)
      .then((results) => {
         console.log(results);
         hideLoader();
      })
      .catch(error => {
         console.error(error);
         hideLoader();
      });
}
```